# Android: Button OnClick not working in SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've tab activity in which i want to use a button, but when i click on button, it force closes the app. Can you please tell me what is going on, i am new to Android.

```
 public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragment {
    private Button bt;
    private Context con;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
        bt = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Toast.makeText(con, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }       
        });

        return rootView;

    }


}
```

Comment: Please, post also home_layout.xml and the error you should view in the logcat.

Why are you using AcionBarSherlock!??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i click on button, it force closes the app

Because `con` object of Context is `null`. which is used for showing Toast message in Button `onClick` method.

Do it as:

```
 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And initialize `con` object by calling `getActivity()` in `onCreateView` as:

```
con=getActivity();
```

Comment: leave the toast aside, when i use something else, onclick doesn't work.

Comment: @EmmJay: see my answer again

Comment: @EmmJay: what u mean by `when i use something else` ??

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid that, don't keep a reference to the context; instead of the

```
private Context con;
```

get the current Activity in the code, so use

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Btw, this seems to be the cause of your crash, as Context is null.